# Problem with Ruby + rtaglib gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, taglib

I need to read ID3 tags from MP3 files, so i did some research and found that rtaglib is the way to go. The other plugins seems outdated, i tried them anyways but none of them work for me.

After installed the rtaglib gem (the ruby binding for TagLib http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html#bindings) i just can't make it work.

I tried adding both the gem to the gemfile and install it with sudo gem install rtaglib. I get the response like it's installed, but after that when i tried to require any of the two files i get:

?> require 'tagfile/tagfile'
LoadError: no such file to load -- tagfile/tagfile
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'

Or if i tried TagLib:

> > require 'TagLib'
> >     => nil

I have tried to move the files manually from the zip file but that doesn't zip to work neither.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu you must install libtagc0-dev first, THEN install the gem.

At first I made the mistake of installing libtag1-dev, which gave me the same problem as you have.

Comment: Whoops, you are using MacOS, so install taglib using brew. (It worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are including rubygems as well. 
If you are doing this from a Rake task or ruby script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tagfile/tagfile'
```

I am doing this on OSX with the gem and taglib installed via homebrew and it works fine.