# LoadError on require 'tagfile/tagfile'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I try to require the tagfile/tagfile which is part of rtaglib I get a LoadError:

```
$ ruby main.rb 
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- tagfile/tagfile (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from main.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I installed rtaglib with

```
$ gem install rtaglib
```

Here is the top part of my main.rb:

```
require 'date'
require 'find'

require 'tagfile/tagfile'
```

None of the suggestions here ([Problem with Ruby + rtaglib gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291544/problem-with-ruby-rtaglib-gem)) work. taglib is installed (1.7.2)

Trying it with other gems, like sinatra, works perfectly. Does anyone know the reason I cannot load rtaglib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just `require 'tagfile'`? I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: which version of ruby do you use? require 'tagfile' returns that PLATFORM is not initialized which seems to be renamed to RUBY_PLATFORM in Ruby >1.9

Comment: It seems that rtaglib is plain and simple outdated. Switched to taglib-ruby (http://robinst.github.com/taglib-ruby/)